# QT WebGL-stream, virtualKeyboard and touch screen problem

Tags: qt, qt5, webgl

As I see, the virtualKeyboard (plugin) sends touch and click event when qml application is running over WegGL-stream. Now I've trouble finding an easy workaround.. Does anyone have a good idea? Further is it a virtualKeyboard or a QPA-Plugin bug?

Tried with QT 5.13.0, MSVC2017 64Bit / MinGW 64Bit compiler, Windows10, Chrome 76.0.3809.132 64Bit / Firefox. If application is not running over WebGL-stream, everthing works fine in terms of touch and click events.

```
// Tests with QT Quick Virtual Keyboard example with extended main.cpp..

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  qputenv("QSG_RENDER_LOOP","threaded");
  qputenv("QT_QPA_PLATFORM", "webgl:port=1051");

  qputenv("QT_IM_MODULE", QByteArray("qtvirtualkeyboard"));

  QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);
  QQuickView view(QString("qrc:/%2").arg("basic-b2qt.qml"));

  if (view.status() == QQuickView::Error)
    return -1;
  view.setResizeMode(QQuickView::SizeRootObjectToView);

  view.show();

  return app.exec();
}
```

Comment: It works with the Microsoft Edge browser.
It seems to be a problem with webqt.js. The Chrom-Console logs this error: 
"Unable to preventDefault inside passive event listener invocation.
handleTouch @ webqt.js:326"